# TicTacToe with GUI in Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I've wrote a program to play TicTacToe.
Here's the class, which contains the method, which checks, whether a player won:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class TicTacToe {
    public static int count = 0;
    public static String[][] board = new String[3][3];

    public static void buttonClicked(JButton button) {
        if(button.getText().equals("")) {
            count++;
            if(count % 2 == 1) {
                button.setText("X");
            }
            if(count % 2 == 0) {
                button.setText("O");
            }
        }   
    }


    public static void gameRules(JButton button) {
        //"X" or "O"?
        String string = button.getText();

        //Gives coordinates of the button
        int x = Character.getNumericValue(button.getName().charAt(0));
        int y = Character.getNumericValue(button.getName().charAt(1));
        board[x][y] = string;

        //diagonal
        if(board[0][0].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][2])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

        }

        //other diagonal
        else if(board[0][2].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][0])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

        }

        //draw?
        else if(count==9) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"draw."); 

        }

        else {

            //row
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if(board[i][0].equals(board[i][1]) && board[i][1].equals(board[i][2])) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

                }
            }

            //column
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(board[0][j].equals(board[1][j]) && board[1][j].equals(board[2][j])) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Here are the other two classes, so now you have the full code:

```java
public class Control {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Gui {
    public Gui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                final JButton button = new JButton();
                String string = i +  "" + j;
                button.setText("");
                button.setName(string);
                button.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            TicTacToe.buttonClicked(button);
                            TicTacToe.gameRules(button);
                        }
                    });
                button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                panel.add(button);
            }

        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);




    }
}
```

My problem is that the program now recognizes when someone wins on a diagonal, but not on rows and columns.

I would appreciate any help to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add a working piece of code?

Comment: As an aside, tic-tac-toe is simpler to code if you use a plain old array, rather than the 2D variety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to import `import javax.swing.*;` for the TicTacToe.java.
Edit the win if statements and delete the static definitions:

```
if(board[0][0] != null && board[0][0].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][2])) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 
} else if(board[0][2] != null && board[0][2].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][0])) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 
} else if(count == 9) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "draw."); 
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[i][0] != null && board[i][0].equals(board[i][1]) && board[i][0].equals(board[i][2])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string + " won."); break;
        } 
        if (board[0][i] != null && board[0][i].equals(board[1][i]) && board[0][i].equals(board[2][i])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string + " won."); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Add `TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();` to the Gui variables.
Change the action listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ticTacToe.buttonClicked(button);
    ticTacToe.gameRules(button);
}
```

Delete `TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();` from the Control.
Always check your errors, you had more NullPointerException exception than you can count.

Comment: Now it works, thanks. But now, I get an NullPointerException, when I click on one of the buttons. Do you know why?

Comment: It only happens, when I click on the first button in the last row. And the error message says it happens in the "ticTacToe.gameRules(button)"-line of Gui.java

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the last if statement, copy the code above again.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204726/discussion-between-onyrew-and-chrysaetos99).

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the null pointer exception.

```
public static void gameRules(JButton button) {
    //"X" or "O"?
    String string = button.getText();

    //Gives coordinates of the button
    int x = Character.getNumericValue(button.getName().charAt(0));
    int y = Character.getNumericValue(button.getName().charAt(1));
    board[x][y] = string;

    //diagonal
    if(board[0][0] != null && board[1][1] != null && board[2][2] != null && 
            board[0][0].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][2]){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 
    } else if(board[0][2] != null && board[1][1] != null && board[2][0] != null && 
            board[0][2].equals(board[1][1]) && board[0][2].equals(board[2][0]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][0])) { //other diagonal
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

    } else if(count==9) { //draw?
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"draw."); 

    } else {
        //row
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if(board[i][0] != null && board[i][1] != null && board[i][2] != null && 
                    board[i][0].equals(board[i][1]) && board[i][1].equals(board[i][2])) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

            }
        }

        //column
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if(board[0][j] != null && board[1][j] != null && board[2][j] != null && 
                    board[0][j].equals(board[1][j]) && board[1][j].equals(board[2][j])) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won."); 

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You don't need to chack the 2. and 3. in one row, column or diagonal, since the 1. isn't null and the equals(null) won't generate an exception there is no point to do so. Also, it's already fixed...